# powerapps Items Function - DataTable - Need to filter zeros in a column & return a grand total at the bottom of table

Tags: powerapps, powerapps-formula

I need help with the formula below. It's currently in the Items function of a datatable.

Could we not show the rows if the value in the data table column is zero. The data table column is "Recorded Time" in Timesheet_DataTable_Container. The source of the data is called October_Timesheets_1D.

Lastly in the same function could we add a grand total table for the Recorded Time column.
Something like this:

Total Hours:                 180

```
Sort(
  Filter(
    October_Timesheets_1D,
    WinTeam_ID = employee_search.Text &&
    DateValue(Date_Formatted) >= ddTimeSelection.Selected.StartDate &&
    DateValue(Date_Formatted) <= ddTimeSelection.Selected.EndDate
  ),
  Date, SortOrder.Descending
)
```

Thanks you for your help.

I tried the removeif formula. I don't know how to use PowerApps formulas yet. I added the formula to the end of the function I have.

[Error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xS7Bc.png)

[Error 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUDOw.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, then add the additional conditional to your filter:

```
Sort(
  Filter(
    October_Timesheets_1D,
    'Recorded Time' <> 0 &&
    WinTeam_ID = employee_search.Text &&
    DateValue(Date_Formatted) >= ddTimeSelection.Selected.StartDate &&
    DateValue(Date_Formatted) <= ddTimeSelection.Selected.EndDate
  ),
  Date, SortOrder.Descending
)
```

And for your total hours, you could try:

```
Sum(
  Filter(
    October_Timesheets_1D,
    'Recorded Time' <> 0 &&
    WinTeam_ID = employee_search.Text &&
    DateValue(Date_Formatted) >= ddTimeSelection.Selected.StartDate &&
    DateValue(Date_Formatted) <= ddTimeSelection.Selected.EndDate
  ),
  'Recorded Time'
)
```

Comment: You did understand my question.Thank you for your reply. I'm just having issues with my data. 
I have the data source from an excel table. Eventually the data will come from a database. 
With that being said, the data in the Recorder Time in excel has been converted to numbers. 

I just get the error below. What can we add to the formula to solve the error?

I received the following error message in the App Checker, under formulas. The error: "The incompatible types for comparison. These Types can't be compared: Control, Number."

Comment: What is `'Recorded Time'`? Try adding a period after to see what properties are there for `'Recorded Time'`. Maybe `'Recorded Time'.Value`. Or when you select the column in the data table, what does the formula say? `ThisItem.xxxx`?

Comment: Recorded time is the total hours column in an excel table. Its currently formatted as a number. The header names in the excel sheet is AUSS Recorded Time. 

For your two other questions please see image above.

Comment: image above called Error 1 & Error 2.

Comment: Suggest you set the `Items` property to just `October_Timesheets_1D`. Then click on the column for `Recorded Time` and see what it says in the formula bar. It should say something like `ThisItem.xxxx`. Then grab the `xxxx` part and update the `Sort( Filter( ... ) ...)` accordingly.